# Are wrapper types really reference type

Tags: java, oop

Look at this code

```
 Integer x=new Integer(55);
 Integer y=x;
 y=33;
 System.out.println(x);//x still prints 55 instead of 33
```

Why does `x` print `55`.

i thought `x` should print `33` since it is reference type..this may be silly but am new to `java`

Comment: All "objects" are really reference types, they are not references to references as you appear to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `y = x`, both `x` and `y` refer to the same Integer object which contains the value 55.

But this line:

```
y = 33;
```

does two things: it creates an Integer object automatically (autoboxing) which has the value 33 and makes the variable `y` point to that new object. At that point, the variable `x` is still pointing to the original Integer (55).

Note: this has nothing to do with primitives:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("abc");
StringBuilder y = x; //y's value is "abc"
y = new StringBuilder("def"); //y's new value is "def", but x's value still is "abc"
```

Comment: `String` is a class type..is `x` getting autoboxed again

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ No autoboxing there but it is a special example indeed. I have edited with a standard object.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `x` print `55`.

Because it **is** a reference type.  This line:

```
y=33;
```

is really short-hand for this:

```
y = Integer.valueOf(33);
```

i.e. a new object is created,<sup>*</sup> and `y` now refers to that instead.  The original object isn't changed, and `x` isn't changed.

---

<sub>* To be pedantic, this isn't necessarily true.  But it will certainly be distinct from the original object.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
y=33;
```

means

```
y=new Integer(33);
```

This is done for you by autoboxing.

Therefore x does not change, you simply assign a new reference to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

The line y=33 creates a new Integer with value 33. x still references the original Integer with value 55.